# Sublime Text 4: open multiple windows from terminal

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

Sublime Text 4 was just released.  A behavior change from Sublime Text 3/2 has been implemented.  In new Sublime Text 4, **if a window is already open** when the User (me) uses the `$ subl .` command from the terminal, it takes me to the **currently open** Sublime Text window.  This is not the behavior I want.

Previously in Sublime 3/2, subsequent use of `$ subl .` command would open a new Sublime Text window in this directory (I would now have 2 separate windows, both in this directory with all of this projects sub-directories in the sidebar).

How do I **get Sublime Text 4 to open Additional Windows from the terminal?**  I would like to open multiple windows in the same project from the terminal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command line argument `-n` or `--new-window` tells `subl` to create a new window.

```
λ subl --help
Sublime Text build 4106

Usage: subl [arguments] [files]         Edit the given files
   or: subl [arguments] [directories]   Open the given directories
   or: subl [arguments] -- [files]      Edit files that may start with '-'
   or: subl [arguments] -               Edit stdin

Arguments:
  --project <project>:    Load the given project
  --command <command>:    Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:     Open a new window
  --launch-or-new-window: Only open a new window if the application is open
  -a or --add:            Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:           Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:     Don't activate the application
  -s or --stay:           Keep the application activated after closing the file
  --safe-mode:            Launch using a sandboxed (clean) environment
  -h or --help:           Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:        Show version and exit

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific
location.
```